# How can I list all processes running with elevated permissions in Windows 7 or above?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

I would like to be able to list all processes running with elevated permissions (i.e. as administrator) on Windows 7 system. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this from the Task Manager, as described [on this article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/319748-process-see-if-running-administrator-elevated.html). 
To summarize, you have to add a new column to the view : **UAC Virtualization**. From the value of this field, you are able to determine whether the process is running elevated or not.

If you want to do this remotely, or via a script, I suggest you to have a look at PowerShell. Particularilly this cmdlet (and its methods) :

```
Get-WMIObject win32_process
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: What about applications that opt-out of UAC virtualization? Oh, I see, the column is actually tristate, and opted-out processes show up as "**Disabled**", but elevated processes show up as "**Not Allowed**". Neat!