# How do I list all process running with integrity level in windows in Java?

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, uac

I am building a scan processes running with admin privilege in Java. But I only found the way list all processes running without tag `UAC` status (Not allowed is for admin) or `integrity` tag like `Process Explorer` . Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java). Please tell me have a way to show these things?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the item you link to just uses a command already available on Linux (`ps`), runs that, and parses its output. The Windows equivalent is `tasklist`.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/816714/46507) shows how to get a more detailed list, via PowerShell, which could be parsed in Java the same way: `powershell "Get-WMIObject win32_process"`

You may have already guessed this: Vanilla Java isn't an appropriate framework for what you're trying to do. Thus the gymnastics involved. Something like JNI might allow you to make a class that makes this easier if the interface needs to be in Java.

Comment: `powershell "Get-WMIObject win32_process"` Only show user name not UAC status or integrity tag

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a command line application that lists the items you're looking for. This leaves using one of the Windows APIs to access this information directly, which is not something that can be done with vanilla Java.